# Oracle complex select query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need help with select statement in Oracle. Due to certain complications, I am not looking for procedure etc. I need to perform this with a single select.

Department:

```
Dept_ID   
-------    
101      
102
```

DepartmentFGStatus:

```
Dept_ID | FG_ID          
------- | -------          
  101   |   ABC  
  101   |   XYZ  
  102   |   ABC
```

CCFGMap:

```
CC_ID | FG_Applicable | FG_ID  
------| ------------- | -------  
FIN   |   Y           |   ABC  
HR    |   N           |   XYZ  
ACI   |   N           |
```

CCStatus :

```
CC_ID | Status  
------| -------   
FIN   |   01  
HR    |   03  
ACI   |   05
```

Need a List of all Dept_ID from  Department table with the following criteria:

> All FG_ID in DepartmentFGStatus table for that Dept_ID should have
>   FG_Applicable = 'Y' and Status of corresponding CC_ID should be 01

Ex: In above example, I need only `Dept 102` in output . 101 does not qualify because it has `XYZ` as `FG_ID` for which `FG_Applicable = 'N'`

Comment: Please format table spacing, so it would be more clear.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join

```
  SELECT d.Dept_ID
  FROM Department d
  INNER JOIN  DepartmentFGStatus dfs on dfs.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID
  INNER JOIN  CCFGMap m on m.fg_id = dfs.FG_ID and m.FG_Applicable ='Y'
  INNER JOIN  CCStatus s on m.CC_ID =s.CC_ID and s.status ='01'
```

Comment: Above query returns both Dept 101 & 102 .

Comment: impossible  check better your data  ..  (the condition   m.fg_id = dfs.FG_ID and m.FG_Applicable ='Y'  select jiust one row   ---> FIN and also m.CC_ID =s.CC_ID and s.status ='01')

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Select 
    d.Dept_ID
from 
    Department d
inner join DepartmentFGStatus dfgs
    on d.Dept_ID = dfgs.Dept_ID
where exists (
    select 
        cm.FG_ID 
    from 
        CCFGMap cm
        inner join CCStatus cs
            on cm.CC_ID = cs.CC_ID 
            and cs.Status = '01'
    where
        FG_Applicable = 'Y'
        and cm.FG_ID = dfgs.FG_ID
)
```

Comment: Thanks Rudolf, however above returns both departments. In above example, I need only Dept 102 in output . 101 does not qualify because it has XYZ as FG_ID for which FG_Applicable = 'N'

Comment: Hi, the exists should filter out those records based on that flag, are you sure there is only one record with the flag set to 'Y' ?